# Flex : How to hide a row in AdvancedDataGrid?

Tags: apache-flex, advanceddatagrid, show-hide, invisible

I have an AdvancedDataGrid with a ArrayCollection as its dataProvider. For instance i have a CheckBox that allows me to show or hide certain rows in the AdvancedDataGrid.

Any idea how i could do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use your data provider's `filterFunction` property. Basically, you can give your data provider a function that will determine whether a given item in the ArrayCollection is excluded or not (if an item is excluded, it won't be displayed in the AdvancedDataGrid, in essence making it "invisible"). The docs for `filterFunction` can be found [here](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/collections/ListCollectionView.html#filterFunction).

What I'd suggest then is that checking the checkbox sets a property on the object in your data provider, which is then used by your filter function to include/exclude rows. Some (very rough) pseudocode follows:

```
private function checkboxClickHandler( event:MouseEvent ):void
{
    /*
       Based on the MouseEvent, determine the row 
       in the data grid you're dealing with
    */

    myDataProvider[someIndex].checkboxFlag = myCheckBox.selected;
    myDataProvider.refresh(); // calling refresh() re-applies the filter to
                              // account for changes.
}

private function myDataProviderFilterFunction( item:Object ):Boolean
{
     // assuming we want the item to be filtered if checkboxFlag is true
     return !item["checkboxFlag"];
}
```